# Grep without filtering

Tags: bash, shell, grep

How do I grep without actually filtering, or highlighting?

The goal is to find out if a certain text is in the output, without affecting the output. I could `tee` to a file and then inspect the file offline, but, if the output is large, that is a waste of time, because it processes the output only after the process is finished:

```
command | tee file
file=`mktemp`
if grep -q pattern "$file"; then
  echo Pattern found.
fi
rm "$file"
```

I thought I could also use grep's before (`-B`) and after (`-A`) flags to achieve live processing, but that won't output anything if there are no matches.

```
# Won't even work - DON'T USE.
if command | grep -A 1000000 -B 1000000 pattern; then
  echo Pattern found.
fi
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Something like a "pretend you're grepping and set the exit code, but don't grep anything".

(Really, what I will be doing is to pipe stderr, since I'm looking for a certain error, so instead of `command | ...` I will use `command 2> >(... >&2; result=${PIPESTATUS[*]})`, which achieves the same, only it works on stderr.)

Comment: I don't want to suppress any of the command's output.

Comment: You can achieve what you want, but the problem is as soon as a match is found by the `grep` the `command` too gets terminated leaving no use in preserving the output (as the command got stopped inbetween). Can you explain what is the goal you are tying to achieve ?

Comment: The goal is to find out if a certain error was output by a program. I want the error to also be printed to the terminal at the time at which it occurred, because the error may depend on context that was also output on stdin, and to cache all errors to a file and echo them only at the end would destroy that relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is set the exit code if a pattern is found, then this should do the trick:

```
awk -v rc=1 '/pattern/ { rc=0 } 1; END {exit rc}'
```

The `-v rc=1` creates a variable inside the Awk program called `rc` (short for "return code") and initializes it to the value 1. The stanza `/pattern/ { rc=0 }` causes that variable to be set to 0 whenever a line is encountered that matches the regular expression `pattern`. The `1;` is an always-true condition with no action attached, meaning the default action will be taken on every line; that default action is printing the line out, so this filter will copy its input to its output unchanged. Finally, the `END {exit rc}` runs when there is no more input left to process, and ensures that `awk` terminates with the value of the `rc` variable as its process exit status: 0 if a match was found, 1 otherwise.

The shell interprets exit code 0 as true and nonzero as false, so this command is suitable for use as the condition of a shell `if` or `while` statement, possibly at the end of a pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

To allow output with search result you can use awk:

```
command | awk '/pattern/{print "Pattern found"} 1'
```

This will print "Pattern found" when `pattern` is matched in any line. (Line will be printed later)

If you want Line to print before then use:

```
command | awk '{print} /pattern/{print "Pattern found"}'
```

---

**EDIT:** To execute any command on match use:

```
command | awk '/pattern/{system("some_command")} 1'
```

**EDIT 2:** To take care of **special characters** in keyword use this:

```
command | awk -v search="abc*foo?bar" 'index($0, search) {system("some_command"); exit} 1'
```

Comment: I want to find out if the output contained a certain string, without modifying the output in any way.

Comment: Yes i know, this is what this awk does, it doesn't change the output at all except adding a `"Pattern found"` line

Comment: Since I don't want any lines to be added, but rather I want to execute code when the line is found, how would I achieve that with awk? I suppose worst case I could make it write a signal to a file? (ugly)

Comment: That line in awk `print "Pattern found"` can be changed to **execute** any code you have using `system` function.

Comment: Can we put that in the answer?

Comment: 1+, good use of `AWK`. Can you explain me how the `1` in  `awk '/pattern/{system("some_command")} 1'` prints all input lines.

Comment: @KannanMohan: `1` in `awk` command is a shortcut for doing default action which is `print` each line.

Comment: My only concern is that the command that I might run on the output could be full of special characters that need to be escaped. So perhaps a simple command like setting a variable could be used instead, and then if that variable is non-empty, I can deal with it after the fact. The downside of that would be that I'd need to wait for the command to be fully finished before being able to take action on the match string.

Comment: see updated **EDIT 2** for avoiding regex so that you can use any special character.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to print out each line of your output, but at the same time, track whether or not a particular pattern is found. Simply passing the output to `sed` or `grep` would affect the output. You need to do something like this:

```
pattern=0
command | while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    if grep -q "$pattern" <<< "$lines"
    then
        ((pattern+=1))
    fi
done
if [[ $pattern -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "Pattern was found $pattern times in the output"
else
    echo "Didn't find the pattern at all"
fi
```

---

### ADDENDUM

> If the original command has both stdout and stderr output, which come in a specific order, with the two possibly interleaved, then will your solution ensure that the outputs are interleaved as they normally would?

Okay, I think I understand what you're talking about. You want both STDERR and STDOUT to be grepped for this pattern.

STDERR and STDOUT are two different things. They both appear on the terminal window because that's where you put them. The *pipe* (`|`) only takes STDOUT. STDERR is left alone. In the above, only the output of STDOUT would be used. If you want both STDOUT and STDERR, you have to *redirect* STDERR into STDOUT:

```
pattern=0
command 2>&1 | while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    if grep -q "$pattern" <<< "$lines"
    then
        ((pattern+=1))
    fi
done
if [[ $pattern -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "Pattern was found $pattern times in the output"
else
    echo "Didn't find the pattern at all"
fi
```

Note the `2>&1`. This says to take STDERR (which is File Descriptor 2) and redirect it into STDOUT (File Descriptor 1). Now, both will be piped into that `while read` loop.

The `grep -q` will prevent `grep` from printing out its output to STDOUT. It will print to STDERR, but that shouldn't be an issue in this case. Grep only prints out STDERR if it cannot open a file requested, or the pattern is missing.

Comment: Will stdout and stderr print interleaved as they normally would when running the command?

Comment: @MihaiDanila Interleave where? Are you talking about `grep`? The `grep -q` will stop STDOUT from printing. To quiet STDERR, you need to append `2> /dev/null` to the command. However, grep usually prints to STDERR only if the file you specified isn't found (which isn't the case here).

Comment: @MihaiDanila Interleave where? Are you talking about `grep`? The `grep -q` will stop STDOUT from printing. To quiet STDERR, you need to append `2> /dev/null` to the command. However, grep usually prints to STDERR only if the file you specified isn't found (which isn't the case here).

Comment: If the original command has both stdout and stderr output, which come in a specific order, with the two possibly interleaved, then will your solution ensure that the outputs are interleaved as they normally would?

Comment: See Addendum in my answer.

Comment: stderr and stdout need to be kept separate, in case a downstream command using my command wants to process only one of the two.

Comment: You can't send then both as separate streams through a pipe and keep their identity.

Comment: Then perhaps the solution is to not send both through a pipe?

Comment: @MihaiDanila You said that you needed STDERR and STDOUT as _interleaved_. That's why I redirected STDERR onto STDOUT. Don't need STDERR, or you want to process it later, it can be saved in a file or sent to `/dev/null`. You can't have both in a stream to have them _interleaved_, and keep them separate. Clarify what you need in your question, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I want to run a command without modifying its output characteristics, but I need to peek at its stdout (or stderr, same deal). I think your original example might work fine. It probably keeps things interleaved if they were interleaved to begin with, without redirecting one to the other. I just wasn't sure, so I wanted to ask you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
echo "'search string' appeared $(command |& tee /dev/stderr | grep 'search string' | wc -l) times"
```

This will print the entire output of `command` followed by the line:

```
'search string' appeared xxx times
```

The trick is, that the `tee` command is not used to push a copy into a file, but to copy everything in `stdout` to `stderr`. The `stderr` stream is immediately displayed on the screen as it is not connected to the pipe, while the copy on `stdout` is gobbled up by the `grep`/`wc` combination.

Since error messages are usually emitted to `stderr`, and you said that you want to grep for error messages, the `|&` operator is used for the first pipe to combine the `stderr` of `command` into its `stdout`, and push both into the `tee` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. It will not modify anything of output of `your-command` and sed exit with 0 when pattern is found, 1 otherwise. I think its what you want from my understand of your question and comment.:

```
if your-command | sed -nr -e '/pattern/h;p' -e '${x;/^.+$/ q0;/^.+$/ !q1}'; then
  echo Pattern found.
fi
```

Below is some test case:

```
ubuntu-user:~$ if echo patt | sed -nr -e '/pattern/h;p' -e '${x;/^.+$/ q0;/^.+$/ !q1}'; then       echo Pattern found.;     fi
patt
ubuntu-user:~$ if echo pattern | sed -nr -e '/pattern/h;p' -e '${x;/^.+$/ q0;/^.+$/ !q1}'; then       echo Pattern found.;     fi
pattern
Pattern found.
```

Note previous script fails to work when there is no ouput from `your-command` because then sed will not run sed expression and exit with 0 all the time.